# Stop Android Application being Started at Bootup

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I am creating an application which can help me to start my application after boot-up ( i.e. at start) and I am able to accomplish it through various discussion available on it on stackoverflow.

Now I want to my application to stop the applications that are running in background at the start. How to stop these applications.

Well I am able to find such kind of applications like : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autostart
This application shows that we can start our an application after device boot-up(i.e. at start) without rooting the device

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.startupmanager.full&hl=en
This application can help us control the enabling and disabling the applications for being started at the device start up. 
I want to know how to reverse engineer the second application and manage the applications at startup.

Please provide links and reference for it . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to this question is , we can start the application after booting ( i.e. at the start ) without Root Access, but to stop the application to run after the boot-up process we need sufficient root privileges to disable or stop such apps.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/how-can-i-stop-applications-and-services-from-running
Provides a viable solution.
https://github.com/ndagrawal/android-autostarts
This is the source code for the application that can help to start as well as to stop other application to start or stop at the bootup.